# Too Many Redirects Issue - Authentication Flow

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

I Have an authentication flow as follows:
I set authentication below to allow access.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

function check($username, $password){
    $_SESSION['Authenticated'] = true;
    $_SESSION['Expires'] = time() + 3600;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("location: ../index");
    exit;
    };
 };

check($username, $password);
?>
```

On every page requiring authentication I include:

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../scripts/check-auth.php';
?>
```

Which calls this script:

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isset($_SESSION['Authenticated']) && $_SESSION['Authenticated']){
    if($_SESSION['Expires']< time()){
        $_SESSION["status_code"] = "401";
        header('Location: ../views/login.php');
        exit;   
    }
    $_SESSION['Expires'] = time() + 3600;
    if($page == '/views/login.php'){
        header('Location: ../index.php');
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION["status_code"] = "401";
    if($page != '/views/login.php'){
        header('Location: ../views/login.php');
        exit;
    }
};

?>
```

The flow works fine for initial authentication however if it expires and then re-login it produces the error too many redirects.
anyone able to assist?

Comment: can you show the code of the login?

Comment: and also let us know, is the re-login and login uses the same script?

Comment: @RayA update the authentication script to include full logic - i've not included how i check if they are allowed access because it calls another api but simply put if that is a 200 response then they are given the session variables

In terms of question 2: it calls check-auth which validates the authentication and then returns them to login.php (this is the same page as the login when they load). Its the check-auth that causes the loop

Comment: do you use `check-auth` in `/views/login.php`?

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `check-auth.php`, you need to unset the variables since you are going to redirect the user to the login page anyway:

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isset($_SESSION['Authenticated']) && $_SESSION['Authenticated']){
    if($_SESSION['Expires']< time()){
        unset($_SESSION['Authenticated']);
        unset($_SESSION['Expires']);
        $_SESSION["status_code"] = "401";
        header('Location: ../views/login.php');
        exit;   
    }
    $_SESSION['Expires'] = time() + 3600;
    if($page == '/views/login.php'){
        header('Location: ../index.php');
        exit;
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION["status_code"] = "401";
    if($page != '/views/login.php'){
        header('Location: ../views/login.php');
        exit;
    }
};

?>
```

If you don't want to unset the variables, just remove the lines of the `unset()` and replace it with this line:

```
$_SESSION['Authenticated'] = false;
```

This should address the issue.

Comment: Perfect I went with the second option and it solves the issue.